# Changing the grub

Tags: grub2

I have the following OS's installed.

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. Windows 7
3. Ubuntu 13.04

After logging into Ubuntu 13.04, I tried modifying the Grub using `Grub-customizer`. It doesn't change anything. Why is that?

Comment: did you run this command: `sudo update-grub` after making any change?

Comment: What are you trying to do with?