# Grub Customizer inconsistent with actual boot menu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

**Background:**

Initially, I created a small partition on a hard drive to try Ubuntu as an alternative to the previously installed Windows XP. After finding Ubuntu useful and running into space problems on that small partition, I created a new bigger one next to it and installed Ubuntu (same version) there again. The boot menu was updated correctly after both installations but since I didn't need the smaller Ubuntu partition any more, I deleted it - leading to a boot menu entry pointing to a non-existent installation. After [learning about Grub Customizer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100246/181442), I was able to delete (or hide, whatever) the boot menu entry of the old Ubuntu installation and set the new one as default, everything was fine.

**Problem:**

After I received an update today (kernel image or something, not sure how to find out what it was exactly), suddenly the old boot menu entries are back at system boot:

[image: boot menu screenshot]

An interesting detail is that since the update, the top two entries show the new kernel version `3.8.0-35-generic`, even though the entry for the "current" (existent) Ubuntu installation (under which I received the update) is the 6th from the top, i.e. the one on `/dev/sdb7`, which still shows `3.8.0-29-generic`.

The Grub Customizer still showed the menu the way I had configured it previously (removed 2 top entries pointing to the old Ubuntu installation as well as the "Previous Linux versions" entry):

[image: Grub Customizer screenshot]

I already tried running `update-grub` [as found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342511/changing-the-grub#comment437897_342511), but this still seems to find the old (`3.8.0-29-generic`) version, although I am unsure if they are really reported correctly:

```
friendfx@Laptop:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for friendfx: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Microsoft Windows XP Professional on /dev/sdb2
done
```

...and, more importantly, after rebooting the menu at system boot is still the same, i.e. *with* the old and "Previous Linux versions" entries.

**Question:**

What can I do to get the configuration I set in Grub Customizer to apply to the actual boot menu at system start? Did I miss anything obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda
```

Comment: I am always a little scared by something like this... how can I check what /dev/sda really is before modifying it somehow? Ah, got an idea: I can use the Disk Utility program. I'll give it a go and let you know, thanks in the meanwhile...

Comment: It worked, accepted your answer. If you care, could you also explain why it worked and I had to use it instead of `update-grub`? What's the difference? Thanks again!

Comment: update-grub updates grub configuration in /boot/grub directory. so everything is kind of set. but the grub in MBR is not aware of this. had the same problem. i guess grub-install /dev/sda rewrites stuff in MBR so grub loader is aware of new configuration. i cannot explain it in more technical terms.

Comment: That's good enough for me :) ...upvoted your answer.